# Laravel IoC Multiple Subclasses Bindings: how to make sure it'll be resolved correctly

Tags: php, laravel-4, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

The title would be vague due to my English. Hope someone can improve it.

**Here is the thing:**

I have one abstract class `Validator`.

Currently, I have two subclasses, `LoginValidator` and `SignupValidator` , which extend from `Validator`.

I have two services: `LoginService` and `SignupService` and they have the same
`function __construct(Validator $validator)`

I wrote two `ServiceProvider`s to bind the `Validator`.

`LoginServiceProvider.php`

`$this->app->bind('Validators\Validator','Validators\LoginValidator');`

`SignupServiceProvider.php`

`$this->app->bind('Validators\Validator','Validators\SignupValidator');`

Therefore, the `$validator` in `__construct(Validator $validator)` is actually always resolved to `SignupValidator`. **I know the reason.**

**I wonder if there is any way to make sure that:**

```
class LoginService {
  //$validator will be LoginValidator
  function __construct(Validator $validator){}

}

class SignupService {
  //$validator will be SignupValidator
  function __construct(Validator $validator){}
}
```

**OR**

I'm simply wrong, I should do `__construct(LoginValidator $validator)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered by someone [here at Laravel.io](http://laravel.io/forum/02-12-2014-laravel-ioc-multiple-subclasses-bindings-confusion)
I found it useful so I am posting the link here
-Thanks